# Junit: How to assert with Get Class Instance

Tags: java, junit

I have the following class `BridgeMaps`:

```
public class BridgeMaps {
    private static final BridgeMaps INSTANCE = new BridgeMaps();

    private Map<String, String> docTypeMap;
    private Map<String, String> docBaseMap;
    private Map<String, String> tempFolderIdMap;
    //....

    //constructor for the class to initialize the Maps      
    private BridgeMaps(){
        docTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        docBaseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        docBaseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //....rest of the code

    }


    //Get the class instance 
    //@return BridgeMaps - Returns the BridgeMaps Instance
    public static final BridgeMaps get(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And I wrote the Junit test case as:

```
public class BridgeMapsTest {

    private static BridgeMaps bridgeMaps;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        Constructor<BridgeMaps> b = BridgeMaps.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
        b.setAccessible(true);
        bridgeMaps = b.newInstance(new Object[0]);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        //("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

But I am not sure what to assert:

`assertWhat(bridgeMaps.get());`

How can I assert the instance of the class in testGet() method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Test is not required actually but I am doing it to fix the sonar scan criticals. Can you please clarify me on `nonNull(BridgeMaps.class) `?

Comment: it worked thank you. :) The problem was in the private constructor, there was another line `cacheUtil = (CacheUtil) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("cacheUtil", CacheUtil.class);`, when I commented out that line, `assertThat(BridgeMap.get(), is(notNullValue(BridgeMaps.class)));` worked!

Comment: happily did that! :))

Comment: That was quick; thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use assertThat.

This assert works with Hamcrest matchers, like [notNullValue()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#notNullValue(java.lang.Class)).

Allowing you to rewrite your assert like this:

```
assertThat(BridgesMap.get(), notNullValue(BridgeMaps.class))
```

This code asserts that calling that static get method will returns a non-null value.

In other words: this call will trigger the ctor, and runs all that code behind that. And you can be assured that your singleton is "real", and not null; respectively causes exceptions upon being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `assertSame(a,b)`

> Asserts that two objects refer to the same object.

Also consider just doing `assertSame(bridgeMaps.get(), bridgeMaps.get())` instead of that reflective pokery.

Comment: I would create without using reflection but the constructor is private. I can't do that right? Can I? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Make another static method. Package scoped.

    static final BridgeMaps create(){
        return new BridgeMaps();
    }

Use it to create the INSTANCE and then use create() from your unit tests.